# JustBasic, getting "bad nesting error select/case" in code

Tags: nested, subroutine, basic, select-case

Pretty new to programming, sorry if basic question, first time doing modular work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but line 41 ([ShowBalance] --> Case"C" spits out the error in the title when I try to run my program. What is nested improperly?

```
Balance=1000
Print "Banking Menu"
Do
Gosub[Menu]
Gosub[Deposit]
Gosub[Withdrawal]
Gosub[ShowBalance]
Loop Until Choice$="Q"
Print "Thanks for using the Banking Application"
End

[Menu]
Print "A. Deposit"
  Print "B. Withdrawal"
  Print "C. Show Balance"
  Print "Q. Quit"
  Input "Make Selection: ";Choice$
  Select Case Upper$(Choice$)
Return

[Deposit]
Case "A"
      Input "Enter Amount to Deposit: ";Dep
      If Dep > 0 Then
        Balance=Balance+Dep
      Else
        Print "Invalid Amount"
      End If
Return

[Withdrawal]
Case "B"
        Input "Enter Amount to Withdraw: ";Wdrw
        If Wdrw <= 1000 Then
            Balance=Balance-Wdrw
        Else
            Print "Invalid Amount"
Return

[ShowBalance]
Case "C"
      Print
      Print "*********************************"
      Print "*** Account Balance: $";using("####.##",Balance);" ***"
      Print "*********************************"
  End Select
  Print
  Print "----------------------------"
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Case` instructions belong to the `Select Case` instruction. They must not get separated! *Your program must always respect below layout without intervening `Return` instructions*.

```
  Select Case <expression>
    Case <values>
      <action>
    Case <values>
      <action>
    Case <values>
      <action>
  End Select
```

### Solution without subroutines

You insert the instructions that perform the action directly below the corresponding `Case` instruction. Disadvantage is that, if the number of instructions in an action block is elevated, you loose track of the whole `Select Case` construct.

```
Balance=1000
Print "Banking Menu"
Do
  Gosub[Menu]
Loop Until Choice$="Q"
Print "Thanks for using the Banking Application"
End

[Menu]
  Print "A. Deposit"
  Print "B. Withdrawal"
  Print "C. Show Balance"
  Print "Q. Quit"
  Input "Make Selection: ";Choice$
  Select Case Upper$(Choice$)
    Case "A"
      Input "Enter Amount to Deposit: ";Dep
      If Dep > 0 Then
        Balance=Balance+Dep
      Else
        Print "Invalid Amount"
      End If
    Case "B"
      Input "Enter Amount to Withdraw: ";Wdrw
      If Wdrw <= 1000 Then
        Balance=Balance-Wdrw
      Else
        Print "Invalid Amount"
      End If
    Case "C"
      Print
      Print "*********************************"
      Print "*** Account Balance: $";using("####.##",Balance);" ***"
      Print "*********************************"
      Print
      Print "----------------------------"
  End Select
Return
```

### Solution with subroutines *Deposit*, *Withdrawal*, and *ShowBalance*

You place the instructions that perform the action in separate subroutines and insert a mere `Gosub` directly below the corresponding `Case` instruction. Advantage is that, even if the number of instructions in an action block is elevated, you keep a clear view on the whole `Select Case` construct.

```
Balance=1000
Print "Banking Menu"
Do
  Gosub[Menu]
Loop Until Choice$="Q"
Print "Thanks for using the Banking Application"
End

[Menu]
  Print "A. Deposit"
  Print "B. Withdrawal"
  Print "C. Show Balance"
  Print "Q. Quit"
  Input "Make Selection: ";Choice$
  Select Case Upper$(Choice$)
    Case "A"
      Gosub[Deposit]
    Case "B"
      Gosub[Withdrawal]
    Case "C"
      Gosub[ShowBalance]
  End Select
Return

[Deposit]
  Input "Enter Amount to Deposit: ";Dep
  If Dep > 0 Then
    Balance=Balance+Dep
  Else
    Print "Invalid Amount"
  End If
Return

[Withdrawal]
  Input "Enter Amount to Withdraw: ";Wdrw
  If Wdrw <= 1000 Then
    Balance=Balance-Wdrw
  Else
    Print "Invalid Amount"
  End If
Return

[ShowBalance]
  Print
  Print "*********************************"
  Print "*** Account Balance: $";using("####.##",Balance);" ***"
  Print "*********************************"
  Print
  Print "----------------------------"
Return
```